# Why do I get this error when connecting to IBM MQ?

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq, message-queue

I want to connect to IBM MQ but I get the error

> **IBM.WMQ.MQException**: 'MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED'

on the line

```
_queueManager = new MQQueueManager(managerName, connectionParameters);
```

I have access to the queue manager.

This is the class MQClient.cs:

```
public class MQClient: IMQClient
    {
        private MQQueueManager _queueManager;
        private Hashtable _connectionParams;
        private string _managerName;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource> _queueListeners = new Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>();

        public MQClient()
        {
        }


        public IMQClient Connect(string managerName, Hashtable connectionParameters)
        {
            _managerName = managerName;
            _connectionParams = connectionParameters;
            _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(managerName, connectionParameters);
            return this;
        }


        public IMQClient Connect(string managerName)
        {
            _managerName = managerName;
            _connectionParams = GetConnectionParameters();
           return Connect(managerName, _connectionParams);
        }


    private Hashtable GetConnectionParameters()
    {
        var parameters = new Hashtable
        {
            {MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT},
            {MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, AppSettings.MQ.Host},
            {MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, AppSettings.MQ.Port},
            {MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, AppSettings.MQ.Channel}
        };
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppSettings.MQ.User))
        {
            parameters.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, AppSettings.MQ.User);
        }
        return parameters;
    }
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface IMQClient : IDisposable
    {
        IMQClient Connect(string managerName, Hashtable connectionParameters);
        IMQClient Connect(string managerName);
        IMQClient StartReadingMessagesFromQueue(string queueName, Action<MQMessage> callback, int retryCount = 0, Thread threadToAbortOnException = null);
        IMQClient StopReadingFromQueue(string queueName);
        IMQClient StopReadingFromAllQueues();
        IMQClient PutMessageInTopic(string topicName, string message);
        IMQClient PutMessageInQueue(string queueName, string message);
    }
```

This is the class MQ from AppSettings.cs:

```
public static class MQ
{
      public static string Host { get; private set; }
      public static int Port { get; private set; }
      public static string Channel { get; private set; }
      public static string Topic { get; private set; }
      public static string Queue { get; private set; }
      public static string User { get; private set; }
      public static string Manager { get; private set; }
 
         static MQ()
          {
             Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.Host"];
             Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.Port"]);
             Channel = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.Channel"];
             Topic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.Topic"];
             User = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.User"];
             Queue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.Queue"];
             Manager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ.Manager"];
                }
    }
```

And the call:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mqClient = new MQClient();
    mqClient.Connect("QMDEVEXT");
}
```

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you connect with IBM toolset?  Are you using ODBC?  If so check properties in Control Panel : Administrative Tools : ODBC Data Sources.   What driver are you using?  Is driver latest?

Comment: Check what error shows up in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG file, this will tell you the cause of the MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED.

Comment: Your program will be connecting to MQ using the UserId that the program is running under and NOT the UserId 'MQ.User' that you set in the AppSettings class.

Comment: jdweng, I don't think it has something to do with the drivers. JoshMc, the administrator of the MQ server found the AMQERR01.LOG file on the IBM AIX machine, but it contains very old records. Roger, I have tried to run my Visual Studio with a different user, but I get the same error. Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: Turn on the queue manager '**_Authority Events_**' and do the test again.  Then use a tool like SupportPac MS0P, MQ Visual Edit or MO71 to view what the exact reason for the 2035 reason code.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for your involvement! I have solved this issue. Seems that my UserId was authorized to use another channel. So, to make it work, I had to change my channel from App.config with one that can be accessed by my UserId and then run Visual Studio as a different user. Thanks @Roger! Your first message helped me to dig in the right direction.